# Custom ProgressBar Indicator not showing up before time consuming action

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I implemented the custom progressbar indicator in my Windows Phone 8 project. It works fine if I try to toggle the indicator with a button. But of course I want it to show up while I perform time consuming actions (filling a list with many items). But as it blocks the UI the progressbar indicator doesn't show up before the action but only afterwards. I tried `.UpdateLayout()` on the indicator itself and the whole page before performing modifications to the list but none of it worked.

```
customIndeterminateProgressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

// add ~100 list items

customIndeterminateProgressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could offload your time consuming work to a new task and add a continuation to set progress bar visibility at the end. Here i'm using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve this:

```
customIndeterminateProgressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

Task.Run(() =>
{
   // Do CPU intensive work
}).ContinueWith(task =>
{
   customIndeterminateProgressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should run your heavy job asynchronously (more about async at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and at the [Stephen Cleary Blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)) - so that it won't block UI.

The very simple example where you have a ProgressBar and a heavy `Task` which will inform PBar about its progress can look like this: (I've subscribed the start of the method to Button Click)

```
private async void StartBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var progress = new Progress<double>( (p) =>
        {
            progresPB.Value = p;
        });
    await DoSomething(progress); // start asynchronously Task with progress indication
}

private Task<bool> DoSomething(IProgress<double> progress)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskComplete = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    // run your heavy task asynchronous
    Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // work divided into parts
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);    // some heavy work 
                progress.Report((double)i / 10);
            }
            taskComplete.TrySetResult(true);
        });
    return taskComplete.Task;
}
```