# UWP Progress Bar in Async method C#

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am developing application where I am processing images. Image processing take sometime (for about 10 seconds). I want to add a progress bar to complete unless image processing in done. I have this progress bar in xaml

```
<ProgressBar Width="200"                               
Foreground="#FF8B64C3"
Value="20" 
Maximum="100" 
BorderBrush="#FF411F72" 
BorderThickness="1"/>
```

This is the event that is called when button is clicked for image processing

```
private void ProcessImageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{          
    applyFilters(image1Pixels, image1Width, image1Height);          
}
```

I want to start progress bar when this ProcessImageButton button is clicked. This is the applyFilters method.

```
 private async void applyFilters(byte[] pixels, uint width, uint height)
 {
        ProcessImage processImage = new ProcessImage(pixels, width, height);

        byte[] effect = processImage.applyEffect(width, height);

        WriteableBitmap result_image = new WriteableBitmap((int)width, (int)height);
        using (Stream stream = result_image .PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(effect, 0, effect.Length);
            MainImage.Source = result_image ;
        }
 }
```

I want my progress bar to complete before storing result_image into MainImage.Source.

Comment: What's your problem? What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you need to show the progress of your work or you want an indeterminable progress bar?

Comment: @Romasz  I want a progress bar during the applying filter process on the image.

Comment: @Herdo I know that I can increment the value attribute of progress bar at the back end code which i have tried like myProgress.Value++; But I don't know how will it be incremented automatically during the process of apply filter on image. I don't even know how much time will it exactly take to complete applying filter on the image, because image size can be different every time.

Comment: Then I think you should be able to divide your work (for example Writing) into smaller chunks, probably via buffer and use *Progress* class to report changes to UI ([here is a sample I've written one day](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23183990/2681948), you will surely find more). I may also think about redirecting your work to separate thread.

Comment: If you do NOT know the time an operation will take, you SHOULD use a progress ring, not a progress bar!

Comment: @Herdo I think there should be some way to get this work. I have seen many apps contain progress bar that load at different speed every time. In case of ring, when I activate ring, inside button click event, it doesn't get activated. If you have any good example of progress ring inside async method, kindly share. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

you can use a indeterminate progress bar

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="ImageProgressBar" Visibility="Collapsed" IsIndeterminate="true"/>
```

and you need to change the visibility before and after the image is loaded

```
        ImageProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        ImageProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<ProgressRing x:Name="progress"  Height="50" Width="50" IsActive="False" />`

and set `progress.IsActive = true;` in the beginning of the operation and

```
progress.IsActive = false;
```

at the end of the operation

Comment: No, I want to use progressBar not ring. And the solution you have showed does not work in case of progressRing. I tried it by putting progress.IsActive = true; at the start of my button click event and it didn't get visible.

Comment: Of  course it works, i have used it many times. For your occasion you can use whatever you like